# magento 2.1 create category attribute thumbnail

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

create category attribute thumbnail.
i create require file as per new magento 2.1 
This is my category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/category_image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

when i upload image i show following error

```
{error: "The file was not uploaded.", errorcode: 666}
error: "The file was not uploaded."
errorcode: 666
```

i am not sure this is magento 2.1 bug ya something wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code seems good. but you missed one minor mistake here.

as per above `category_form.xml` code you created new field `<field name="thumbnail">`.
So newly created element name will be `thumbnail` here.

but you are using core module controller to perform upload operation.

```
<item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/category_image/upload"/>
</item>
```

and in this controller core code has been paasing `image` field name for image element. `i.e.`

```
$result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('image');
```

so difference is here. You should be pass your custom field name `i.e.` `thumbnail`

**Solution**

1. Create your own controller class in your custom module. e.g. `app/code/namespace/modulename/Controller/Adminhtml/Category/Image/Upload.php`
2. Copy whole code from above class and paste into your class.
3. replace fieldname '`image`' with `thumbnail`

   `$result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('thumbnail');`

**Please you can get complete solution [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129870/magento-2-create-category-attribute-thumbnail-and-upload-image-using-file-upload/129871#129871) Marius answer completely.**