# Magento 2 create category attribute thumbnail and upload image using File Uploader Component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category-attribute, uicomponent

I've created a custom module to display category thumbnail image.
I've read magento [dev doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-uploader.html) 
It is displayed in my category section using `category_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="categorylist/category_thumbnailimage/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

when i upload image i showing following error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $baseTmpPath of Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader.

Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $baseTmpPath of Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader.
```

my controller file is

```
<?php

namespace Company\Categorylist\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * Class Upload
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $baseTmpPath;
      /**
     * Image uploader
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader
     */
    protected $imageUploader;

    /**
     * Upload constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader
    ) {
        $this->imageUploader = $imageUploader;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }
   public function execute() {
        try {
            $result = $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir('thumbnail');
            $result['cookie'] = [
                'name' => $this->_getSession()->getName(),
                'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
                'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
                'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
                'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
        }
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)->setData($result);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you need to add this in the `di.xml` of your module.

```
<type name="Company\Categorylist\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Thumbnailimage\Upload">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

this is needed because the dependency of your controller called `imageUploader` is an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader`. This is just a general class for upload that does not have the base path and base tmp path set. So it does not know where to upload the files.
But in the `etc/di.xml` file of the catalog module you have this virtual type defined:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">catalog/tmp/category</argument>
        <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">catalog/category</argument>
        <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
            <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
            <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
            <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

This means that `Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload` class does not actually exist, but when this is used you will actually use an instance of the class you are expecting `Magento\Catalog\Model\ImageUploader` but it has the required member vars (`basePath`, `baseTmpPath` and `allowedExtensions`) already set.

Comment: marius, i have directly http://pastebin.com/Qn8dX3Zz add  the code at vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml and getting the error  `The file was not uploaded.` error

Comment: why i getting this error

Comment: maybe because the file was not uploaded? I don't know exactly why

Comment: Hi, @Marius. After saving category image not display in position.

Comment: Check this out: https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-image-attribute-to-a-category-in-magento-2.html

Comment: @mirus this is not working in magento 2.2.3

Comment: After saving the model, the image not move to `basePath` in the product custom image uploader. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this issue on github [category image attribute issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5978/files)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create you own $baseTmpPath and $basePath, then you gonna need to do this after @Marius solution.
Put this in your Upload.php

```
public function execute()
{
    $imageId = $this->_request->getParam('param_name', 'image');

    try {
        $this->imageUploader->setBaseTmpPath('Aht_BannerSlider/tmp/images');
        $this->imageUploader->setBasePath('Aht_BannerSlider/images');
// some code ...
```

For example: Aht_BannerSlider is my module name.
Thanks @Marius

Comment: After saving the model, image save in `Aht_BannerSlider/images` path?

Comment: i think so, its a long time since i posted this answer, so you can try by your own. :)

Comment: It is save in `Aht_BannerSlider/tmp/images` path while upload image. But not save to `Aht_BannerSlider/images` path.