# Create image category attribute on magento 2.1

Tags: attributes, magento-2.1, category-attribute

I have created category image attribute according to the [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129883/magento-2-1-custom-category-image-attribute-is-not-saved?newreg=3bf6a729791a4d118d3cb950645c2249) post. Images are also saving successfully. But I cannot preview or delete image as default category image. I had written code in category_form.xml, content of this file.

```
<field name="homebanner">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Home Banner</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="categoryattr/index/homebanner"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```