# Adding custom Image attribute for category in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have tried below code for adding thumbnail image in category.

When i upload image in custom field i get below error.

**Error**

> Attention
>
> The file was not uploaded.
>
> **error: "The file was not uploaded." errorcode: 666**

**category_form.xml**

```
<field name="thumbnail_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/category_image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thumbnail Image</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

**InstallData.php**

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'thumbnail_image', array(
    'input'   => 'image',
    'type'    => 'varchar',
    'backend' => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
    'group' => 'General',
    'label'         => 'Thumbnail Image',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'frontend_input' =>'',
    'global'        => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible_on_front'  => 1,
));
```

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/di.xsd">
<type name="Namespace\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Image">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\CategoryImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

Comment: check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/129870/magento-2-create-category-attribute-thumbnail-and-upload-image-using-file-upload

Comment: Please check updated question still i have same issue

Comment: check this module on github https://github.com/pratikmage/magento2-subcategory

Comment: @Pratik I checked that module now error not showing file upload successfully  but image not stored in db

Comment: it's bug in magento and it's fix by following patch  https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/5978/files